# tkinter comboxes don't appear after converting the GUI app to a .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I have created a GUI application with tkinter for data analysis. In the app I have several comboxes to list down the sheets of an uploaded excel file. The user can select a sheet name from the combox and the code will read the columns to process the data analysis.

Everything works in Python environment without producing an error. I converted the tkinter application by using both pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe.

My problem is tkinter comboxes aren't functional in the .exe. They worked perfectly in the .py script but in .exe they are not even appearing after uploading. What could be the possible issue for this?

with pyinstaller I used the command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed name_of_script.py
```

and with Auto Py I browsed to my program and converted it.

this is how I created comboxes in .py

```
proboxATC = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=proATC_com, value=pathATC_sheets,state='readonly')

proboxATC.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",ATC_selected)
```

Here is a minimum working example. As you can see it works as a .py but the combox doesn't appear in the .exe.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkmacosx import Button
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')

def OOE():        
   pathxl = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [('Excel files', '*.xls*')], title = "Select an ATC file")  
   excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(pathxl)
   sheet_names = excel_file.sheet_names
   combo = tk.StringVar()
   def selected(event):
       print(box.get())                
 
   box = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=combo, value =sheet_names, state='readonly')
   box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",selected)
   box.pack()

xl_btn = Button(root,text="ATC",foreground='#161327',background="#707087",command=lambda:OOE())
xl_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is used to populate the comboboxes? If they're getting data from a file (for example) you'll probably need to include that file in the executable with pyinstaller's `--add-data` command

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: yes they are getting data from excel files uploaded. But that's not one single file it can be many depending on the uploaded choice.

Comment: Try creating a console executable instead (without `--windowed` command line argument when running PyInstaller) and see whether there is error showing in the console after selecting a Excel file. When I run the converted executable, I get "missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'" error.  After adding `--hidden-import openpyxl` when running pyinstaller to generate the executable, it works.

Comment: @acw1668 converting .py with the console opened first was a great solution! And indeed it said openpyxl was missing, and then I imported it as a hidden file. Now everything works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile and run your program fine.  I did have to add the following line to the imports at the top in order to get the filedialog to work, but I don't think this is necessary on all systems.

```
import tkinter.filedialog   # added this line
```

And I also added `openpyxl` to the --hidden imports flag for pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller -F -w --hidden-import openpyxl main.py
```

Comment: Exactly what was the issue! I imported openpyxl as a hidden file and now it works smoothly! Thank you so much!